# DateTimePicker и WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

Можно ли подключить DateTimePicker из WinForms в проект WPF?

Comment: Разумеется. А что не выходит? Вы не забыли добавить System.Windows.Forms.dll к проекту?

Comment: А, подождите, это **контрол**, а не окно?

Comment: Может быть, вам подойдёт DatePicker? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.aspx

Comment: @VladD, сборку WinFowms к проекту подключил, а в xaml прописал  xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms". Все равно в xaml не могу создать DateTimePicker.

Comment: @VladD, да, это контрол. А DatePicker не подходит.

Comment: см. [WindowsFormsHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost(v=vs.100).aspx) -- для использования WinForms контролов в WPF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в WPF проект сборки `System.Windows.Forms` и `WindowsFormsIntegration`, а в xaml добавьте:

```
xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
```

и

```
<WindowsFormsHost>
   <wf:DateTimePicker />
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

---

**UPDATE**

DateTimePicker можно привязать, например, к Slider, чтобы с его помощью менять значение текущей даты

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window2"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:app="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
  Title="Window2" Height="150" Width="300">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <WindowsFormsHost><app:Picker x:Name="dp" /></WindowsFormsHost>
    <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="9" 
       IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" TickFrequency="1" x:Name="sldr">
       <Slider.Value>
         <Binding 
           Path="CurrentDay"
           BindsDirectlyToSource="True"
           ElementName="dp"
           UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
           Mode="OneWayToSource" />
       </Slider.Value>
    </Slider>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=dp, Path=Value}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WpfApplication1 {
    public class Picker : DateTimePicker {
        public double CurrentDay {
            set { this.Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(value); }
        }
    }
    public partial class Window2 : Window {
        public Window2() {
            InitializeComponent();
            dp.MinDate = DateTime.Today;
            dp.MaxDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(sldr.Maximum);
        }
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Правильный путь — не использовать контролы из Windows Forms, а контролы написанные для WPF.

В принципе, для WPF есть [`DatePicker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.aspx), и во многих случаях его достаточно. Если нет, вы можете подключить [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) (вот [nuget-пакет](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extended.Wpf.Toolkit/)), и использовать [`DateTimePicker`](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimePicker) оттуда.

Вы можете подключить и контрол из WinForms, используя [`WindowsFormsHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), но у вас не будет должным образом работать Binding.

---

<sup>Основано ответах к [этому вопросу](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10658472/276994).</sup>

Comment: _"не будет должным образом работать Binding"_ -- привязка к свойствам работает. например, TextBox привязывается к `DateTimePicker.Value`, а Slider.Value можно привязать к DateTimePicker через ObjectDataProvider.

Comment: @Stack: Ну да, всё, что не требует DependencyProperty, работает. Наверняка прямой Binding не катит.

Comment: _"Наверняка прямой Binding не катит."_ -- если прямой это, например, такой `{Binding ElementName=dp, Path=Value}`, то работает. см. мой [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489993/196972) после update.

Comment: @Stack: У вас обратный, `OneWayToSource`. В другую сторону (от `DateTimePicker`а к другим элементам) по идее не сработает.

Comment: _"У вас OneWayToSource"_ -- да. Slider.Value передает значение в DateTimePicker.Value. _"В другую сторону (от DsteTimePickerа к другим элементам) по идее не сработает."_ -- работает. т.к. значение выводится в TextBox.Text

Comment: @Stack: Вы точно уверены, что работает? А если изменить значение из code-behind? А так пойдёт: `<app:Picker x:Name="dp" Value="{Binding PropertyInVM}"/>`?

Comment: _"уверены, что работает?"_ -- в ответе есть gif. на нем видно, что TextBox.Text меняется при изменении Slider.Value.

Comment: @Stack: `<app:Picker x:Name="dp" Value="{Binding Birthday}"/>` вылетает при разборе XAML. Так что с прямым Binding'ом не получится. Судя по всему, с Binding'ом к VM проблема принципиальная.

Comment: _"<app:Picker x:Name="dp" Value="{Binding Birthday}"/> вылетает при разборе XAML"_ -- правильно. picker для wpf - это как обычный объект, такой же как, например, `class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged { /*...*/ }`.

Comment: @Stack: Кроме того `<Slider.Value><Binding Path="CurrentDay" BindsDirectlyToSource="True" ElementName="dp" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay" /> </Slider.Value>` (с `TwoWay`!) не работает даже с геттером `CurrentDay`.

Comment: @Stack: Ну да. Вот поэтому-то я и говорю, что привязка не будет работать. «Работает только в некоторых случаях» == «не работает».

Comment: _"поэтому-то я и говорю, что привязка не будет работать. «Работает только в некоторых случаях» == «не работает»."_ -- привязка `<app:Picker x:Name="dp" Value="{Binding Birthday}"/>` -- да, не будет работать, т.к. Picker - это не WPF-контрол. но изменение Slider'а передается в свойство DateTimePicker, а также изменение свойства DateTimePicker.Value транслируется в TextBox.Text. и по-идее больше ничего и не надо. хотя не знаю. возможно, что у объекта типа Data надо сделать привязку к его свойству Some, вроде такой Some="{Binding Birthday}"?

Comment: @Stack: Ну, обычно нужно привязать свойства контрола к VM, а не к другому контролу. У меня такое не получилось. И поскольку контролы WinForms не поддерживают INotifyPropertyChanged, это судя по всему и вовсе невозможно.

Comment: @Stack: Традиционный путь — у вас есть свойство Birthday в VM, и вы говорите `Value="{Binding Birthday}"`. При этом изменения в VM подхватываются контролом, а изменения в контроле отправляются в VM. У меня не получилось ни то, ни другое. Ваш код связывает два _контрола_, но хочется ведь контрол с VM.

Answer (score 1):

я бы сказал что правильный путь - не использовать заранее известные нерабочие контролы, к которым по праву можно отнести DateTimePicker из WPF Toolkit.

В версии библиотеки 3.0 он абсолютно неработоспособен:

1) при потери фокуса текст HH:mm:ss смещается на 1 позицию вправо (то, что было минутами, станет часами, то, что было секундами, станет минутами. секунды обнулятся)

2) при нажатии на клавиши влево-вправо срабатывает алгоритм 1, с тем дополнением, что пока часы не обнулятся, фокус на следующий компонент контрола не перейдёт.

говорят что в новой версии (3.1 и 3.2) это исправлено, но тратить ни одну из запрашиваемых разработчиками сумм (2000$, 1000$, 500$) чтоб протестить это, я не готов.

Не вижу альтернативы, кроме как или писать свой контрол, либо использовать виндовый, несмотря на то что у него не работают криво-описанные биндинги.

Comment: Ну, если 3.0 не работает хорошо, а 3.1 не доступно, почему бы не использовать 2.9? Там описанных вами багов я не вижу. Какой-то у вас максимализм, ей-богу.